# Add Textfield MDCAlertController IOS

Tags: swift, uialertcontroller, material-components-ios

There is no method similar to the addtextfield method in Uialertcontroller. I haven't found any examples of how I can customize MDCAlertControllers. Anybody have an idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is not possible. The [docs](https://material.io/develop/ios/components/dialogs/api-docs/Classes/MDCAlertController.html#/c:objc(cs)MDCAlertController(im)addAction:) say:

> MDCAlertController class is intended to be used as-is and does not
>   support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and
>   must not be modified.

Answer (score 1):

This is now possible by using `accessoryView`. 
Simply set it to be your custom view and set the alert message to be blank.

`alertController.accessoryView = myCustomView`

---

#### Code example (using SnapKit for layout)

```
let title = "My title"        
let alertController = MDCAlertController(title: title, message: "")
let confirmAction = MDCAlertAction(title:"Confirm") { [weak self] _ in
    //your action here
}
let cancelAction = MDCAlertAction(title:"Cancel")

let width = UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.91
let testView = UIView()
let button = UIButton()
button.setTitle("Test", for: .normal)
testView.addSubview(button)
button.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
    make.center.equalToSuperview()
}
testView.backgroundColor = .blue //just to show where the view is
testView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
    make.width.equalTo(width)
    make.height.equalTo(100)
}

alertController.accessoryView = testView
alertController.addAction(confirmAction)
alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
alertController.defaultTheming()

present(alertController, animated:true)
```

#### Result from above code

[image]